# C++ : Array of Objects of a Class with Overloaded Constructors

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, copy-constructor, constructor-overloading

Suppose i have a class "myclass" -:

```
class myclass
{
public:
    int n;
    myclass(int n=0)
    {
        this->n=n;
    }
    myclass(myclass &a)
    {
        this->n=a.n;
    }
    ~myclass()
    {
        cout<<n<<"\n";
    }
};
```

Now i want to create an array of objects of "myclass" as follows -:

```
int main()
{
    myclass arr[]= {5};  // Only 1 element for simplicity...
}
```

But when i do this , i get the following error -:

*In function ‘int main()’:

|47|error: no matching function for call to ‘myclass::myclass(myclass)’

|47|note: candidates are:

|36|note: myclass::myclass(myclass&)

|36|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘myclass’ to ‘myclass&’

|32|note: myclass::myclass(int)

|32|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘myclass’ to ‘int’*

But when i remove the copy constructor  `myclass(myclass &a)` from the class , i don't get any errors and everything works fine...

So now my questions are -:

**1). Why is this happening?? Isn't  `myclass(int n=0)` a better match than the copy constructor here??**

**2). How to successfully compile it , considering I want both , the copy constructor as well as the integer constructor in my class??**

NOTE: I am using GCC version 4.7.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 ( If it is of any relevance. )

Comment: Shouldn't a copy constructor take a `const myclass& a`?

Comment: @nvoigt Both are legal, and there are rare cases (like `std::auto_ptr`) where the copy constructor does take a non-const reference.  But generally: you want to be able to copy temporaries (which requires a const ref), and you don't modify the object being copied (so you can use a const ref).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization semantics in this case are copy
initialization.  Copy initialization formally converts the
arguement, then copies it.  The converted arguement is not an
lvalue, so it cannot bind to the non-const reference in your
copy constructor.  If you don't define the copy constructor,
the compiler defines one for you, which takes a const
reference.  You're copy constructor should take a const
reference as well, since it doesn't modify its argument.

Note that the compiler is allowed to optimize out the copy
construction.  But only if the program would be legal if it
didn't.

Comment: I would have voted it up but I don't have enough reputation.I'll vote it as soon as i get some. Thanks for the help anyways..!!

Answer (score 2):

> How to successfully compile it , considering I want both , the copy constructor as well as the integer constructor in my class?

Adding `const` to the reference argument of the copy constructor fixes this problem:

```
myclass(const myclass &a) : n(a.n) {}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/a7rMV9).

Comment: Oh yeah! Forgot that "5" is a  const value.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi `5` has type `int`, not `int const`; it's an rvalue, so cannot be cv-qualified.  And the `5` serves as argument to `myclass( int )`.  It's the copy of the temporary object created by `myclass( int )` which fails if the copy constructor takes a non-const reference.

Comment: @JamesKanze You are right! But what do you mean by "cv-qualified" exactly??

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Being qualified by `const` or `volatile`.  ("cv-qualified" is the term used in the standard for this.)